# Swiftでの２値の引数を持つ関数の記述方法

Tags: swift

下の画像のように２つの値を引数とする関数を定義し、
使用すると以下のようなエラーがでます。
[image: エラー画面]

```
plus(5,b:10)
```

とすればエラーはなくなるのですが冗長に思います。
Swiftではこのように記述しなければならないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plus(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

plus(33, 44) // 77
```

このように、アンダーバーを使って、引数のラベルを省略できます。

この関数の構文の基本形はこうです。

```
plus(a x: Int, b y: Int) -> Int {
    return x + y
}

plus(a: 22, b: 33) // 55
```

外部引数のラベル`a`と`b`と内部引数`x`と`y`を、別の名称にする場合の構文です。これの外部引数のラベルを、アンダーバーで省略することで、ラベルのない関数の構文を作れるというしだいです。

Swiftは、関数、メソッドの引数にラベルが付くのが基本形。そして、関数では、第一引数のラベルは省略されます。これらはおそらく前身のObjective-Cを継承しているのだと考えられます。

アンダーバーは、このような使い方もします。

```
for _ in 1...10 {
     print("Hello")
}
```

単純にHelloと10回出力するプログラムです。10回をカウントするけれども、カウントした値を使う必要がないというとき、アンダーバーを使うと、むだに変数を作らなくてすみます。